# Datagrids and AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am currently using the fl.controls.DataGrid in my as3 application. In addition to very frustrating bugs, it seems to have very bad performances especially when your data size increases. 
Is there a simple way to make an efficient datagrid with as3?

Answer (score 1):

The best success I have had is with setting as few of the properties as possible, tying the data to a simple AS object class  that contains only the data properties and writing it directly to an ArrayCollection.    If your class includes a 'label' property you can pretty much get away without setting anything but the dataprovider (which I emphasize should always be an arraycollection; I forego the creating an array then 'wrapping' it in an arrayCollection) but having a tightly bound model for the data seems to improve the useability.  I have heard that using xml data offers a slight improvement, but I prefer pure AS classes, which outperform mxml by a mile.

It always has been that all my AS3 woes stem from the display end of things.  Pure AS3 would be a God-send if they could come up with  a replacement for  mxml.

P.S. avoid item editors! they work great if you only have 50 records, but the grids are designed to DISPLAY data ((a pure text grid of 250k records should scroll fine....) Always edit the data, not the grid. Pull the data into a form to edit.  The data binding will take care of updating the grid.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there an alternative to fl.controls.DataGrid?

Comment: not in Flash, but there are spark and mx data grids, as well as an mx.controls.advancedDataGrid which are part of the Flex framework